# I want to select random questions from a Table from each catogories

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, random

SQL Server 2005 query needed, please help.

I have a table which have questions and all questions are categorized TopicWise wise.

[image: Table Questions]

And another table which Contains topic and its weightage of number in the Subject

[image: Table Topics]

Now, I need to select 50 random questions from Table `QUESTIONS` which are based on the weightage of the Topic like out of 50 random selected questions there must be

```
5 questions from Subtopic_Id=1 and    
15 questions from Subtopic_Id=2 and
10 questions from Subtopic_Id=3 and
10 questions from Subtopic_Id=4 and
10 questions from Subtopic_Id=5
```

See Second image (Table Topics)

and the number of topics and their weightage may vary in different subjects, so union statement will be a bad idea for a dynamic query.

I even have not figure out a single bit of line of code for this selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column values in your TOP clause. Not a common knowledge but it can be done.

You can make use of `TopicWeightage` column in your TOP clause.

It can be done but its just there are very rare chances you would ever write a query like this. you happen to be in such a situation hence the solution would be something like.....

```
SELECT Q.ExamQ_ID
FROM TopicTable t 
              CROSS APPLY ( 
                           SELECT TOP (t.TopicWeightage) ExamQ_ID
                           FROM Questions
                           WHERE SubjTopicID =  t.SubjTopic_ID
                           ORDER BY NEWID()  
                           ) Q(ExamQ_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any other way than using dynamic sql and, for each subtopic, doing a query with an order by rand and get the top x number.

Comment: @JamshaidRiaz Basically, what benjamin moskovits has in his answer, but create it as a string of text with a query then use exec on that string

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from (select Top 5 *
 from questions where subtopic_id=1
order by NEWID())a1

 union

select * from (

select Top 10 * 
 from questions where subtopic_id=2 
from dbo.spegg_AtgPrice_Diff
order by NEWID())
a2

and so on
```

Comment: Dear Benjamin, there are 10 Subjects, and every subject has different number of topics like in the image there are 5 topics but there is a subject which has 10 topics. so doesn't union statement will create a mess code.

Comment: This will be hell of a poor query as you will be going through the whole table as many as Subject types you have.  Also who would wrtie this query if you have say 50 subject types :)

Comment: Creating it for 5 topics would take 3 more cut and pastes. This seems like a one time project. If it was recurring I would suggest an index on subtopic_id and then it would run quite quickly. I could not see the 'second image' so I don't know what requester meant by 'number of topics and their weightage may vary in different subjects.'